MPLS L3 VPN, issue with customers pinging
I created the MPLS L3 VPN architecture(screenshot in the link at the end of the post)  using ARISTA vEOS images, then I got a problem with network reachability between the CE client routers.  please can anyone help me to troubleshoot the issue. I give you the configuration done below
I configured the following items:
 **CE1 configuration**

    CE1(config-if-Lo0)#sh startup-config

    ! Command: show startup-config

    ! Startup-config last modified at  Thu Jul  4 17:27:16 2024 by admin

    ! device: CE1 (vEOS, EOS-4.19.10M)

!

    ! boot system flash:/vEOS-lab.swi

!
transceiver qsfp default-mode 4x10G
!
hostname CE1
!
spanning-tree mode mstp
!
no aaa root
!

    interface Ethernet1
       no switchport
       ip address 192.168.1.1/30
       ip ospf area 0.0.0.0

!




!
!

    ip routing

!

    router ospf 1
       router-id 4.4.4.4
       network 4.4.4.4/30 area 0.0.0.0
       network 192.168.1.0/30 area 0.0.0.0
       max-lsa 12000
    !

end
CE1(config-if-Lo0)#

**CE2 configuration**

CE2(config-if-Lo0)#sh startup-config
! Command: show startup-config
! Startup-config last modified at  Thu Jul  4 20:16:40 2024 by admin
! device: CE2 (vEOS, EOS-4.19.10M)
!
! boot system flash:/vEOS-lab.swi
!
transceiver qsfp default-mode 4x10G
!
hostname CE2
!
spanning-tree mode mstp
!
no aaa root
!
interface Ethernet1
   no switchport
   ip address 192.168.3.1/30
   ip ospf area 0.0.0.0
!
interface Ethernet2
!
interface Ethernet3
!
interface Ethernet4
!
interface Ethernet5
!
interface Ethernet6
!
interface Ethernet7
!
interface Ethernet8
!
interface Ethernet9
!
interface Ethernet10
!
interface Ethernet11
!
interface Ethernet12
!
interface Loopback0
   ip address 5.5.5.5/30
!
interface Management1
!
ip routing
!
router ospf 1
   router-id 5.5.5.5
   network 5.5.5.4/30 area 0.0.0.0
   network 192.168.3.0/30 area 0.0.0.0
   max-lsa 12000
!
end
CE2(config-if-Lo0)#


    **PE1 configuration**

hostname PE1
!
spanning-tree mode mstp
!
no aaa root
!
vrf definition CE1
   rd 1:100
!
interface Ethernet1
   no switchport
   ip address 192.168.1.2/30
!
interface Ethernet2
!
interface Ethernet3
   no switchport
   ip address 10.10.1.2/30
!
interface Ethernet4
!
interface Ethernet5
!
interface Ethernet6
!
interface Ethernet7
!
interface Ethernet8
!
interface Ethernet9
!
interface Ethernet10
!
interface Ethernet11
!
interface Ethernet12
!
interface Loopback0
   ip address 2.2.2.2/30
!
interface Management1
!
ip routing
ip routing vrf CE1
!
mpls ip
!
mpls ldp
   router-id 2.2.2.2
   transport-address interface Loopback0
   no shutdown
!
router bgp 1
   router-id 2.2.2.2
   neighbor 3.3.3.3 remote-as 1
   neighbor 3.3.3.3 update-source Loopback0
   neighbor 3.3.3.3 maximum-routes 12000
   !
   address-family ipv4
      neighbor 3.3.3.3 activate
      redistribute ospf3
   !
   vrf CE1
      route-target import 1:100
      route-target export 1:200
!
router ospf 1 vrf CE1
   redistribute bgp
   max-lsa 12000
!
end
PE1(config)#

    **PE2 configuration**

hostname PE2
!
spanning-tree mode mstp
!
no aaa root
!
vrf definition CE1
   rd 1:100
!
interface Ethernet1
   no switchport
   ip address 192.168.3.2/30
!
interface Ethernet2
!
interface Ethernet3
   no switchport
   ip address 10.10.4.2/30
!
interface Ethernet4
!
interface Ethernet5
!
interface Ethernet6
!
interface Ethernet7
!
interface Ethernet8
!
interface Ethernet9
!
interface Ethernet10
!
interface Ethernet11
!
interface Ethernet12
!
interface Loopback0
   ip address 3.3.3.3/32
!
interface Loopback9
!
interface Management1
!
ip routing
ip routing vrf CE1
!
mpls ip
!
mpls ldp
   router-id 3.3.3.3
   transport-address interface Loopback0
   no shutdown
!
router bgp 1
   router-id 3.3.3.3
   neighbor 2.2.2.2 remote-as 1
   neighbor 2.2.2.2 update-source Loopback0
   neighbor 2.2.2.2 maximum-routes 12000
   !
   address-family ipv4
      neighbor 2.2.2.2 activate
      redistribute ospf3
   !
   vrf CE1
      route-target import 1:200
      route-target export 1:100
!
router ospf 1 vrf CE1
   redistribute bgp
   max-lsa 12000
!
end
PE2(config)#


    **P1 configuration** 

hostname P
!
spanning-tree mode mstp
!
no aaa root
!
interface Ethernet1
   no switchport
   ip address 10.10.1.1/30
!
interface Ethernet2
   no switchport
   ip address 10.10.4.1/30
!
interface Ethernet3
!
interface Ethernet4
!
interface Ethernet5
!
interface Ethernet6
!
interface Ethernet7
!
interface Ethernet8
!
interface Ethernet9
!
interface Ethernet10
!
interface Ethernet11
!
interface Ethernet12
!
interface Loopback0
   ip address 1.1.1.1/30
!
interface Management1
!
ip routing
!
mpls ip
!
mpls ldp
   router-id 1.1.1.1
   transport-address interface Loopback0
   no shutdown
!
router ospf 2
   router-id 1.1.1.1
   network 1.1.1.1/32 area 0.0.0.0
   network 10.10.1.0/30 area 0.0.0.0
   network 10.10.4.0/30 area 0.0.0.0
   max-lsa 12000
!
end
P(config)#



  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/8MSznMiT.jpg


It looks like you have several problems:

I don't think you have a working link-net between PE1 & PE2
You're missing an IGP so your iBGP session probably can't come up
PE interfaces (Ethernet1 on PE1 & PE2) aren't in the VRF you created
Doesn't appear you have a valid PE-CE routing protocol configuration or default routes on CE1 & CE2 so they know to use the L3VPN to reach each-other


I resolved the BGP issue between the PEs, and configured an OSPF process in the CEs with ID 1 and redistribute the routes, however the reachability issue between the CEs still exist, : below the CE s configuration
hostname CE1
!
interface Ethernet1
no switchport
ip address 192.168.1.1/30
ip ospf area 0.0.0.0
!
interface Loopback0
ip address 4.4.4.4/32
!
ip route 0.0.0.0/0 192.168.1.1
!
ip routing
!
router ospf 1
router-id 4.4.4.4
network 4.4.4.4/30 area 0.0.0.0
network 192.168.1.0/30 area 0.0.0.0
max-lsa 12000
!
